# How to invoke a click button?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need help with invoking method into this class button.
The HTML code on the website for this is shown like this:

```hml
<div class="login-item bottom">
    <span class="pwd-link ng-binding ng-hide" ng-click="forgetPwd()" ng-show="oCap.bSptGuidImport || oCap.bSptQAReset" ng-bind="oLan.forgetPwd">Mot de passe oublié&nbsp;?</span>
    <button class="btn btn-primary login-btn" type="button" ng-click="login()"><label class="ng-binding" ng-bind="oLan.login">Se connecter</label></button>
</div>
```

I tried the codes below using powershell but it doesnt work for the button

```bsh
$xe = New-Object -Com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$xe.Visible = $true
$IURL = 'http://example.com/doc/page/login.asp'

$xe.Navigate($IURL)
while ($xe.Busy -eq $true) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; 
} 

# It's OK for these ID's
$xe.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('username').Value = 'myloginadmin'
$xe.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('password').Value = 'mypassword'

# invoke click button ?                
$xe.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName('button').Click()
```

I have this error message:

```
Échec lors de l’appel de la méthode, car [System.__ComObject] ne contient pas de méthode
nommée « click ».
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ $xe.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName('button').Click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please use translated error messages instead of the localized ones. Not everybody in the world speaks French.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$xe.Document.getElementsByTagName('button').Click()
```